# Necessity to learn haskell language extension for production

Tags: haskell

Haskell core language is really simple. Coming from an OO background, the main difficulty is to adapt to the pure functional paradigm.

While learning "basic" Haskell, I have always considered language extensions as toys for CS people or as experiments for future versions of the language (like `from future import ???` in python).

However when I began to look at web frameworks such as Yesod, I find that a lot of source files require between 3 & 4 extensions. Some look quite simple (StringOverload). Other are really intimidating (GADT, Type Famillies, Template Haskell). Their documentation links to research papers, which is scary for someone expecting to learn "just" a new library.

Is it necessary to learn GHC language extensions to be productive in Haskell? If you were to hire a Haskell developer for a production application, would you ask for such knowledge?

Comment: See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10849782/894284

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it necessary to learn GHC language extensions to be productive in Haskell?

Yes. And that is true for any language/tool. With the core/basic knowledge you can solve the online contest problems, may be small university project, but definitely not real world application.

> If you were to hire a haskell developper for a production application, would you ask for such knowledge?

That now depends on do you have some person with you which can share this knowledge. If yes, then that person can ramp up the new employee. If not then you must get such person with knowledge first. And again this is true for new technologies.

Off-course you could also try to hire peoples having such deep knowledge in Haskell. But Haskell being relatively new into industry and considering very few commercial projects have been done around it, finding such person will be hard. The effective way to build a team of professionals in Haskell, will be to hire people who knew basic and willing to work in Haskell, and then educate them.

Comment: I was going to protest, but then I saw that Real World Haskell teaches many language extension. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: "And that is true for any language/tool" - that's completely false. Say, take such languages as Java, C#, C++ - none of them have language extensions which are commonly found in real world applications code. If you have to use language extensions every time you need to write anything less trivial than "the online contest problem solutions", in my opinion, there's something very wrong with the language spec.

Comment: @Malcolm Why do you find "If you have to use language extensions every time you need to write anything less trivial than "the online contest problem solutions", in my opinion, there's something very wrong with the language spec." to be true? What is the characteristic of an extension that makes it negative? I use ghc and the provided extensions. Adding an extension to an existing project seems just as burdensome as adding another library.

Comment: @Davorak Because instead of a single language we have zillion of different extension combinations, and you don't know anything about whether the code is going to compile on a certain compiler. **Extensions make the code non-portable.** And also this makes the language a pain to learn because instead of a single set of features which everyone uses there is tremendous amount of additional features, and you haven't got a clue which ones you have to know and use and which ones exist just because researchers are having fun.

Comment: @Malcolm - I guess my impression about haskell compiles was that pretty much everyone uses ghc unless you are going something specialized so for most people the portability question is not a problem. "instead of a single set of features which everyone uses there is tremendous amount of additional features," <- I guess my impression of this was it was no worse then having to learn multiple libraries and not know which ones are the best to learn.  Thanks for detailing your understanding.

Comment: @Davorak That's exactly the problem I'm talking about: everyone uses GHC, because this is the only still actively maintained compiler. Other compilers can't keep up, so no one can use them, and there's little reason to invest in them. As for the libraries: you pick libraries for the problem and work only with them. Say, if you need to read XML, you need just one XML-reading library. With extensions, however, it's not obvious when you need which. Though there's a problem with libraries too. Say, in Java there're just arrays and collections, and in Haskell there's a load of array libraries.